# Keyboard print UID MFRC522 Arduino Leonardo

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega32

I want to print the UID of a card as an HID with the Arduino Leonardo.

Here is the code that I have

```
void loop() {
if (  mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {


// Select one of the cards
     if (  mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {



  // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
         mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
         Keyboard.print(mfrc522.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is what the compiler says

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MFRC522::Uid' to 'const Printable&'
exit status 1
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the isse you are facing is that you are trying to print a `MFRC522::Uid` which is a HEX number such as `00 00 00 00` while the `keyboard.print()` only accepts `char`, `int` or `string` according to: [Arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/keyboardprint/). I found the following code snippet [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/rfid-reader-mfrc-522-uid-vs-picc/261212). I believe it might resolve your issue. It should write: `"Card UID: 00 00 00 00"`.

```
Serial.print("Card UID:");    //Dump UID
for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
}
```

**NOTE:** If you are using `Keyboard.print()` I believe you need to use `Keyboard.begin()` in your setup method.